# Chi-square test of independence of 2 variables on a large sample

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, large-data

Is it safe to check the Chi-square test of independence with a sample of 25000 ?

I have the answers of approximately 25.000 people of different countries, as frequencies (total sums for each question). They asked to evaluate a threat based on their perception from 1 to 10 (1: non existent, 10: extremely high) and to reply to some demographics. 
Now i want to check if sex (male, female) correlates with the perception of the evaluation, and secondly if it does, how strong it is.

I read that this test is not safe when the sample is very big (n>250) because then there is a possibility the statistical importance of the relationship of the 2 variables to be “fictive” cause of the overgrowing of the value of chi square.
Unfortunately is not available to quote because it’s not in English.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "check the Chi-square."  There are many tests with "chi-square" in their name, with different objectives, different assumptions, and different scopes of applicability.

Comment: What did you read exactly (i.e. please offer a quote if you can), and where did you read it?

Comment: I tried to clarify it. Is it ok now?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? At very large sample sizes, the test is almost certain to reject the null even on fairly trivially weak levels of dependence, as it should (that's a consistent test doing exactly the job it was asked to do!). If whoever wrote what you're asking about objects to using a test in that situation it's a clear indication that they shouldn't be using a hypothesis test *at any sample size* -- it's answering a different question to the one that should have been asked. All a large sample size is doing is making it blatantly obvious they shouldn't have used a test at all ..ctd

Comment: ctd .... they're misattributing the problem (blaming the test, rather than the initial misconception that statistical significance in hypothesis tests have anything to do with practical effect sizes). If they want to see if there's dependence large enough to be of practical interest, an equivalence test or even a confidence interval (for a given form of dependence) would make considerably more sense.

Answer (score 2):

First, if one variable is a count you might want to use something other than chi-square. Perhaps a t-test or Mann Whitney U. It depends on exactly what you want to check.

Second, I think I can see what the article is talking about. But it's not a question of chi-square (or any test) being "safe" with large N - that looks like some sort of mistranslation. It is true that, with large N, a statistically significant difference may be of no practical importance. If you find a small p with the test, it means the same thing as it always does: If the null (independence) were true in the population, then you'd be unlikely to get a test statistic (chi-square) at least as extreme as the one you got in a sample the size of the one you have.

However, you can also look at the degree to which the null is wrong. Here, how far from equal are the distributions?  The crosstabulation (and associated percentages) will let you get a sense of that.

Comment: As always faster than me and +1 :-)

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply. The case is: i have the answers of approximately of 25.000 people. They asked to evaluate something from 1 to 10 (1: non existent, 10: extremely high). Now i want to check if sex correlates with the perception of the evaluation, and secondly if it does, how strong it is. Thank you again in advance.

Comment: Chi square is not really correlation. You might look at a count regression model.

Comment: Could you help me on how i can do something like this?

Comment: my dependent variable is asking on a scale of 1-10 how much a threat exists (1 is non existent and 10 is extremely high)

Comment: Oh. Then it is not a count. I'd consider an ordinal logistic regression here.

Comment: I treated them: the 1-10 variable as discrete, and the sex as nominal, then i did chi square independence test. The answers i have for the discrete variable are on frequencies, total answers for each level.

Answer (score 2):

There are different aspects to consider.

1. Approximate tests (like the one you are using) tend to provide more accurate p-values for large samples. So you are fine.
2. The power of a test, i.e. its ability to detect a true working hypothesis, tends to increase with larger sample size. Eventually, even small effects can yield small p values. This is not a problem of the test but is related to the third aspect:
3. The "default" working hypothesis of a test (e.g. there is a relation between the two variables, no matter how small) is often not very interesting. This can easily be mended by asking more relevant questions. So instead of asking "Is there *any* true association?" you could ask "Is the true association at least weak?" (e.g. in terms of the population Cramèr's V or population Spearman's rank correlation being larger than a certain threshold in absolute value).

(Combining 2. and 3. we can say that large sample sizes allow us to answer *interesting* questions.)

Comment: Can you please check the modified question and tell me if you have any idea on how I'm gonna work?